# angular md-datepicker is showing 1 day behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

```html
  <md-datepicker  ng-model="objGeneralDetails.strReferenceDate"  name="Dated1" ng-required="false" ng-class="{ datepicker : (!POMain.Dated1.$valid && submitactive )}" md-placeholder="Dated" style="margin-left:-10px;"></md-datepicker>
```

date picker is showing in correct date to model objGeneralDetails.strReferenceDate.

how can i fix this ??

Comment: does your `objGeneralDetails.strReferenceDate` is one day behind?

Comment: no, objGeneralDetails.strReferenceDate is simple a scope object which stores the selected date value of md-date picker.